# Support Vectors

Tags: svm

My professor gave me this definition

All vectors $x_i$ with $y_i.d(x_i,H(w^*,b^*))\leq Margin^*$ (which means that lying inside the tube) is called as support vectors. Does this mean points within the margin that have incorrect class labels are also called support vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

All vector that influence the boundary are included in the set of support vectors. All the mislabeled points contribute to the model.

There might be textbooks that distinguish between the "proper" support vectors and the mislabeled points, but as far as I know, they tend to all be considered "support vectors".

For example, in the Python library Scikit-Learn, the set of support vectors indeed does contain all mislabeled points, but not the correctly labeled points that are too far from the margin (since those do not influence the model).

Comment: their error terms will be 0 ? in case of soft margin SVM?

Comment: The error terms for the mis-labeled points will not be 0. The error terms for the excluded points will indeed be 0.

Comment: Excluded points? which have distance = Margin?